# Removing Rows with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, integer, conditional-statements, rows

Hello I currently have a csv that has all the win/loss of every NBA team from 1948-2018. I have cleaned up most of the data and dropped all the columns I need to, but I am stuck on one particular part. I only need to use the years from 2009-2018 so I need to remove/drop all the other years. I have tried the drop method like this:

```
team_record.drop([1946-47, 1947-48, 1948-49, 1949-50, 1950-51, 1951-52, 1952-53, 1953-54, 1954-55, 1955-56, 1956-57,
                 1957-58, 1958-59, 1959-60, 1960-61, 1961-62, 1962-63, 1963-64, 1964-65, 1965-66, 1966-67, 1967-68,
                 1968-69, 1969-70, 1970-71, 1971-72, 1972-73, 1973-74, 1974-75, 1975-76, 1976-77, 1977-78, 1978-79,             
                 1979-1980, 1980-81, 1981-82, 1982-83, 1983-84, 1984-85, 1985-86, 1986-87, 1987-88, 1988-89, 1989-90,
                 1990-91, 1991-92, 1992-93, 1993-94, 1994-95, 1995-96, 1996-97, 1997-98, 1998-99, 1999-0o0, 2000-0o1,
                 2001-0o2, 2002-0o3, 2003-0o4, 2004-0o5, 2005-0o6, 2006-0o7, 2007-8, 2008-9], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

But it comes back with this error:

```
KeyError: '[1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, -1, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1899, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999] not found in axis'
```

Does anybody know how I can drop those years or correct this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your seasons stored as strings or integers?

Comment: When you write `1946-47`, that's a numeric expression that evaluates to `1899`.

Comment: How do I write it in the code to wear it doesn't evaluate it to 1899?

Comment: You need to quote the index entries that are likely strings:  `team_record.drop(['1946-47', '1947-48',  ...`